# Closed form for a zeta series :$\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{(k+2)2^{k+2}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions, gamma-function, infinite-product

It is not that diffcult to derive
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{k2^k}=&-\frac{\gamma}{2}+\ln\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)\tag{1}\\
\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{(k+1)2^{k+1}}=&-\frac{4+\gamma}{8}+\ln\left(A^{3/2}2^{5/24}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
Hence, I would like to know if there exists a closed form in terms of known mathematical constants for the following series
$$\mathscr{S}=\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{(k+2)2^{k+2}}$$
As $(1)$ and $(2)$ follow immediately from the definitions of $\Gamma(z)$ and $G(z+1)$ respectively, my guess is that the evaluation of $\mathscr{S}$ involves the function $\Gamma_3(z)$. Unfortunately, I know almost nothing about higher order multiple gamma functions, and I would really appreciate it if someone can enlighten me on this matter and provide a viable solution to the series above. Thank you.

---

This is what I have managed to get so far.
Begin with the sum
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{k+1}z^{k+1}
=&\sum^\infty_{k=3}\sum^\infty_{m=1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\frac{z^{k}}{m^{k-1}}\\
=&\sum^\infty_{m=1}\left\{-m\ln\left(1+\frac{z}{m}\right)-\frac{z^2}{2m}+z\right\}\\
\end{align}
Compare this with $\ln{G(z+1)}$.
$$\ln{G(z+1)}=-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^2}{2}+\sum^\infty_{m=1}\left\{m\ln\left(1+\frac{z}{m}\right)+\frac{z^2}{2m}-z\right\}$$
It follows that
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{k+1}z^{k+1}=-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^2}{2}-\ln{G(z+1)}$$
Integrate from $0$ to $z$ to get
\begin{align}
&-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{z^3}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^3}{2}-z\ln{G(z+1)}-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{(k+2)}z^{k+2}\\
=&\sum^\infty_{k=1}\left\{-k(k+z)\ln\left(\frac{k+z}{k}\right)+kz+\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{6k}\right\}
\end{align}
After letting $z=\frac12$, I have no idea how to proceed further as when I take the exponential of the partial sum, the portion with the $\ln$ term doesn't seem to telescope.

Comment: There is a closed form I found using a CAS but I really don't have any idea about the manner it could be derived.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It would certainly be nice if you coud share the closed form. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any problem with that but I cannot prove anything. Is this an assignment given to you ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, it is not (I am still a high school student). Rather this question is purely out of my personal interest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned by Claude Leibovici, you have

> $$
> \sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{(k+2)2^{k+2}}=-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{\gamma}{24}+\frac{\ln 2}{12}+\frac{\ln A}{2}-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{16 \pi ^2}. \tag1
> $$

Here is a **hint**.

From  the [classic identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) verified by the digamma function $\displaystyle \psi:=\Gamma'/\Gamma$, wich may be obtained from the Euler product giving $\Gamma(x+1)$, you have
$$ \psi(x+1) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{k(k+x)}\quad x\neq 0,-1,-2,-3,\dots$$
then you easily obtain, for $|x|<1$,
$$ \begin{align}
\psi(x+1) & = -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{k^2}\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{x}{k}} \\
&= -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{k^n}x^{n+1} \\
&= -\gamma - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \zeta(n+2){x^{n+1}} \\
&= -\gamma - \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1} \zeta(k){x^{k-1}} \\
\end{align}
$$
and
$$-\gamma x^2 - x^2\psi(x+1) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1} \zeta(k){x^{k+1}}. \tag2$$

Using $(2)$ gives

$$
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{(k+2)2^{k+2}}&=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1} \zeta(k)\int_0^{1/2}\!\!x^{k+1}dx\\
&= \int_0^{1/2}\!\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1} \zeta(k){x^{k+1}}\:dx \\
&= -\gamma \int_0^{1/2}\!x^2 dx - \int_0^{1/2}\! x^2\psi(x+1)\:dx \\
&=-\frac{\gamma}{24} - \int_0^{1/2}\! x^2\psi(x+1)\:dx,
\end{align}
$$ then integrating by parts twice leads to 
$$ \begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{(k+2)2^{k+2}} & = -\frac{\gamma}{24} - \frac14\log \Gamma\left(\frac32\right)+2\int_0^{1/2}\! x\log \Gamma(x+1)\:dx\\
&=  -\frac{\gamma}{24} - \frac18\log \pi- \frac14\ln2+\zeta'\left(-1,\frac32\right)+2\int_0^{1/2}\! \zeta'(-1,x+1)\:dx \\
&= -\frac{\gamma}{24}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{\ln 2}{12}+\frac{\ln A}{2}-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{16 \pi ^2},
\end{align}
$$
where we have used the [identity (25.11.34)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#viii)  and [special values](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html) of $\zeta'(s,a)$.

Comment: +1 This answer is really helpful as I am able to compute that last integral $\displaystyle\int^\frac{1}{2}_0x\ln{\Gamma(x+1)}\ {\rm d}x$

Comment: +1. Nice work. $\Psi\left(\, 1 + z\,\right) + \gamma$, as related to ${\tt\mbox{zeta functions}}$, is a well known identity. See ${\bf 6.3.14}$ in
[this link](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm).

Comment: @FelixMarin I knew that link. I just wanted to prove it from another well-known result. Thank you.

Comment: That's fine too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a CAS, the following closed form was obtained $$\mathscr{S}=\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{(k+2)2^{k+2}}=\frac{\log (A)}{2}-\frac{7 \zeta (3)}{16 \pi ^2}-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{\gamma
   }{24}+\frac{\log (16)}{48}$$

By the way, it seems that $$\mathscr{S_n}=\sum^\infty_{k=2}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\zeta(k)}{(k+n)2^{k+n}}$$ has a closed form.

Comment: Why would CAS, whatever that is, write the last summand in the expression above as it did and not $\;\frac{\log2}{12}\;$ ? Perhaps this hints somehow about the way the closed form was obtained?

Comment: Just because it is dumb and I did not time to continue the simplifications ! Cheers :-)